# How can I use a dynamic array value like this location.rating[issue.id] in an ember view

Tags: ember.js

I just want to show only selected out of an array, if they are included in another array but it seems I cannot do this, If you know how I should do this, or if you have a suggestion of how to do it a different way I would be pleased to hear it.

This is my handlebar view,

```
    {{#each App.User.issues}}
        {{#view App.LocationListItemIssueView issueBinding="this" locationBinding="parentView.location"}}
            {{#if location.rating[issue.id] != null}}
                {{location.rating[issue.id].value}}
           {{else}}         
                {{issue.name}} Not Rated    
           {{/if}}      
           {{issue.name}}   
        {{/view}} 
    {{/each}}
```

And I get his error

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 1:
...                 {{#if location.rating[issue.id] != 
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## if doesn't work like if().. it doesn't take a full statement and evaluate it, instead it takes a path to a property that gets converted to a boolean.

If you want to display the intersection of two arrays in a collectionview, then you should create an arrayController, and make content of that arrayController a computed property that figures the intersection of the arrays. Then, bind your collectionview to that array controller.

This would look something like:

```
MyApp.intersectionController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  arrayOneBinding: 'MyApp.firstArray',
  arrayTwoBinding: 'MyApp.secondArray',
  content: function() {
    ... create and return an array which is the intersection of both arrays ...
  }.property('arrayOne.@each', 'arrayTwo.@each').cacheable()
});
```

If you want to render ALL items in the array, but change the template somehow based on the other array, you could do the following in your itemViewClass:

```
rating: function() {
    return this.getPath('location.rating')[this.getPath(content.id)];
}.property('content', 'location').cacheable();
```

and then in your view:

```
{{#if rating}}
  {{rating}}
{{else}}
  {{content.name}} not reated
{{/if}}
```

Comment: okay I figured I couldn't do it like that but I never thought about making an extra controller for it, thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to access a property that's on the parentView, you don't have to bind it to each child view, you can just use the parentView property on the view, so you can do this.getPath('parentVIew.location') instead of binding location to each child view of the collection

Answer (score 0):

This could also be solved with a Handlebars helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(value, options){
    //This would be tweaked to fit your needs. 
    //I'm checking that a passed in value matches the bound value.
    return this.get('content_type') === value ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
})
```

http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: keep in mind #if already does a !! force to boolean on the value, so there's no need to do a comparison. The main problem with the OP's use of #if was that he wasn't using a property path.

Comment: gotcha, I sort of read the post wrong as well and was thinking more like compare the current bound value to a passed in string. Like compare rating == "5-star".